# Java Server Sockets: My Server Socket only allows client connections running on the same internet connection?

Tags: java, sockets

Ok so I have constructed a working example of a client and server which can accept multiple client connections.  My problem is is that I cannot connect a client which is not running the same internet connection as the one the server is being hosted on.  Is this possible using server sockets?

Here is the code for my server:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;

public class MultipleSocketServer {

public static Socket connection;
public static String name = "Tyler's Server";
public static int limit = 2;
public static Thread[] clients = new Thread[limit];
public static int current = 0;
public static int port = 25565;
public static String[] connected = new String[limit];
public static ServerSocket socket;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Server starting...");
    for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        connected[i] = "";
    }
    try {
        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(port);
        while(true) {
            Socket connection = socket.accept();
            String ip = connection.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString().substring(1, 13);
            loop:
            for(int i = 0; i < connected.length; i++) {
                if(connected[0].equals(ip) || connected[1].equals(ip)) {
                    break loop;
                }else if(!connected[i].equals(ip)) {
                    connected[i] = ip;
                    MultiServer_Client client = new     MultiServer_Client(connection, i);
                    Thread run = new Thread(client);
                    run.start();
                    break loop;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        System.out.println("Could not bind server on: " + port);
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
}
```

And here is the rest:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MultiServer_Client implements Runnable {

public String time;
public Socket client;
public StringBuffer process = new StringBuffer();

public BufferedInputStream inputStream;
public InputStreamReader reader;

public BufferedOutputStream outputStream;
public OutputStreamWriter writer;

public StringVis check = new StringVis("");
public StringChangeListener checkListener = new StringChangeListener() {
    public void textChanged(StringChangeEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Changed");
        write("Server recieved message...");
    }
};

public boolean connected = true;
public int ID;

public MultiServer_Client(Socket connection, int i) {
    client = connection;
    ID = i;
    try {
        //declare text input/output
        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "US-ASCII");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException: " + e);
    }
    System.out.println(MultipleSocketServer.connected[ID] + " connected...");
    write("Connected to " + MultipleSocketServer.name);
}

public void run() {
    while(connected) {
        read();
    }
    System.out.println("Disconnecting client...");
}

public void write(String authen) {
    try {
        time = new java.util.Date().toString();
        String message = time + ": " + authen + (char) 13;
        writer.write(message);
        writer.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        connected = false;
        MultipleSocketServer.connected[ID] = "";
    }
}

public void read() {
    //read from client
    int character;
    process = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        while ((character = reader.read()) != 13) {
            process.append((char) character);
        }
        check.setText(process.toString());
        process.delete(0, process.length());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        connected = false;
        MultipleSocketServer.connected[ID] = "";
    }
}
}
```

Here's the client code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class SocketClient {

public static String host = "69.182.134.79";
public static int port = 25565;

public static void main(String [] args) {
    StringBuffer imports = new StringBuffer();
    String time;
    System.out.println("Client starting...");

    try {
        //establish client
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
        Socket connection = new Socket(address, port);

        BufferedOutputStream bos = new     BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(bos, "US-ASCII");

        BufferedInputStream bis = new     BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(bis, "US-ASCII");

        while(true) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            String message = scan.nextLine();

            //write to server
            time = new java.util.Date().toString();
            String process = host + ":" + port + " sent data at " +     time + ": " + message + (char) 13;
            osw.write(process);
            osw.flush();

            //read from server
            int c;
            while ((c = isr.read()) != 13) {
                imports.append((char) c);
            }
            System.out.println(imports);
            imports.replace(0, imports.length(), "");

            if(message.equals("--EXIT")) {
                connection.close();
            }
        }

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("UnknownHostException: " + e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOExcepion: " + e);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Define _same internet connection_ and also, where is your server hosted? (in house, data center, etc.)

Comment: Same internet connection as in the server is running off of my house internet and my client can also only connect while connected to my house internet

Comment: So where are you _not_ able to connect from, outside your LAN? If so, have you forwarded the necessary ports, etc?

Comment: Is there a firewall on the machine running the server? This might prevent incoming connections. Does your internet connection allow incoming connections?

Comment: I have port forwarded my 25565 port yes and correct outside my LAN.

Comment: No there is not.  I used to run a Minecraft server through port 25565 but not anymore so the port is open and should allow connections through. Yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`MultiServer_Client client = new     MultiServer_Client(connection, i);`

to

`MultiServer_Client client = new     MultiServer_Client(new Socket([Server IP], port), i);`

This should work.

Comment: The MultiServer_Client object is passed the connection socket because that is the incoming client connection that needs to be accepted.  I tried that but the client doesn't connect.

Comment: Would I have to use the external IP of my computer from the client?

Comment: Yes. You have to use your internet IP of your server if you are accessing from outside client. Buf if you access in the same server, localhost OR 127.0.0.1 should work.

Comment: I must be having a firewall issue. The client is connecting through this:
String host = "69.182.134.79";
int port = 25565;
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
Socket connection = new Socket(address, port);

Then it sets up the input and output buffers.

Comment: Instead of using InetAddress, you can directly connect by IP OR host name. That also will work. Anyways, good to see that your program is working.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to register the connection from the client to the server. Hahaha I wish the program worked across internet connections.  Does the server need to define what its IP it is running off of? Can I do this manually?

Comment: Any error OR exception you are getting? If so, can pu post that too?

Comment: I am not getting any exceptions or errors. It just wont connect when I use the external IP from the client.  I will post the client code above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7177/discussion-between-ravig-and-mrdrprofessortyler)